# Only two questions show on a newly launched session

Tags: bug, design, search

When booting up a new session (presumably with an empty cache), the number of questions on the new page is exactly two. The option to increase this to 15/30/50 entries is offered (and the change, once made, persists), but the initial impression is very disconcerting.

Background: I'm running on a laptop, away from my usual setup, over guest wifi.  After the CSS relaunch, restarted from scratch, and was greeted with a much "downsized" view.  Now that I've restored my usual page size, I can't recreate the conditions, but it *did* happen.

Comment: I can confirm this: I tried to search the main site and got the awful list of 2 results per page: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qtRpo.png

Comment: same for me....

Comment: I see this issue only after searching for something. Else, i see the complete Main and Meta sites. Can somebody confirm this?